# Shell script to sync ubuntu time with gps device

Tags: ubuntu, gps, ntp

I have a ubuntu box running gpsd and able to gather signal from the sky.

Now I would like to sync my ubuntu time with from this gpsd. Is there any simple shell script can do this? so I can make a crontab job?

Answer (score 1):

You can setup the gpsd as a kind of NTP-TimeServer.
Have a look on this tutorial: http://www.bufferbloat.net/projects/cerowrt/wiki/Getting_time_from_gpsd